# Determining which of the following polynomials is a coset of $I$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification, ideals

I have the following question here:

> Let $I = \{h\cdot(x-1)| h \in \mathbb{Z}[x]\}$, an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, and let $g = x^3+2x^2-x-3$. Which of the following polynomials $f_j$ are in the same coset of $I$ as $g$, i.e., satisfy $f_j + I = g + I$?

> $f_1 = x^3 + 3x^2 - 5$
> $f_2 = 2x^3 + x - 2$
> $f_3 = x^4 + 2x^2 - 4x + 3$ 
> $f_4 = 6x^5 - 6x^4 + x^3 + 2x^2 - x - 3$
> You may use the fact that a polynomial $f\in
> \mathbb{Z}[x]$ is in $I$ if and only if $f(1) = 0$.

I know that in general, if $a+I=b+I$, then we must have that $a-b\in I$.

For the first one:

So this means that $(x^3+3x^2-5)-(x^3+2x^2-x-3)=x^2+x-2=(x-1)(x-2)\in I$ since $(x-1)$ divides $(x-1)(x-2)$.

For the second one:

$(2x^3+x-2)-(x^3+2x^2-x-3)=x^3-2x^2+2x+1$. This is not divisible by $(x-1)$ so it's not a coset.

For the third one:

$(x^4+2x^2-4x+3)-(x^3+2x^2-x-3)=x^4-x^3-3x+6$. This is not divisible by $(x-1)$ so it's not a coset.

For the last one:

$(6x^5-6x^4+x^3+2x^2-x-3)-(x^3+2x^2-x-3)=6x^5-6x^4=6x^4(x-1)$. Here, we can divide by $(x-1)$ so this is a coset.

So only $f_1$ and $f_4$ are cosets of I.

First of all, is my method right?

Second, what was the point of the $f(1)$? Is it to simplify the factoring? I don't see the point of it. I do agree the factoring would be difficult for $f_2$ and $f_3$ but I am not sure how the fact that $f(1)=0$ would help me here.

Comment: You are correct, and the point of $f(1)$ is that it's easy to evaluate $f_j(1)$, so $f_j-g\in I\iff f_j(1)=g(1)=-1$; cf. the [factor theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem)

Comment: As a follow up, I think I am misinterpreting the definition of a coset. Essentially, it's the amount of "shifting" I have to do to the original polynomials (in this case) so it's part of $I$ right? So why do we need the evaluation of both of these to equal $-1$?

Comment: We need $f_j(1)-g(1)=0$, equivalently $f_j(1)=g(1)$

Comment: Ahh thank you! That makes sense now.